# Unable to run jsreportlocal on Azure WebApp Linux (.Net core 2.1 MVC)

Tags: javascript, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.1, jsreport

I have existing .Netcore 2.1 MVC deployed on Azure WebApp Linux.
I need to create reports pdf so I thought to use jsreport local.

```
var rs = new LocalReporting().UseBinary(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ? JsReportBinary.GetBinary() : jsreport.Binary.Linux.JsReportBinary.GetBinary()).Configure((cfg) =>
    {
         cfg.HttpPort = 1000;
         cfg.AllowedLocalFilesAccess().BaseUrlAsWorkingDirectory();
         return cfg;
    }).AsUtility().Create();
var report = await rs.RenderAsync(new RenderRequest
    {
          Template = new Template
         {
              Recipe = Recipe.ChromePdf,
              Engine = Engine.None,
              Content = contentToPrint
          }
    });
```

On windows this code works fine. Once deployed on Web App (Linux) I get the error:

Failed Error rendering report: A critical error occurred while trying to execute the render command: Failed to launch chrome!/tmp/jsreport/compile/jsreport-2.4.0-Bk_dhUp8V/chrome/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directoryTROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md (1). caused by error (1) -> meta = {"remoteStack":"Error: Failed to launch chrome!\n/tmp/jsreport/compile/jsreport-2.4.0-Bk_dhUp8V/chrome/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md\n\n    at onClose (jsreportRuntime.js:400867:14)\n    at Interface.helper.addEventListener (jsreportRuntime.js:400856:50)\n    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)\n    at Interface.emit (events.js:208:7)\n    at Interface.close (readline.js:370:8)\n    at Socket.onend (readline.js:149:10)\n    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)"}, stack = Error:     at responseToBuffer ([eval]:72595:29)    at concat ([eval]:72648:40)    at ConcatStream. ([eval]:17182:43)    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)    at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:208:7)    at finishMaybe ([eval]:97353:14)    at afterWrite ([eval]:97215:3)    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:144:20)    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Comment: now I also tried run it as web server by using .AsWebserver() instead of .AsUtility() but got below error:

Comment: Failed Failed to start jsreport server, output: 2019-04-07 - [34mdebug[39m: Extension authentication was disabled2019-04-07 - [34mdebug[39m: Extension authorization was disabled2019-04-07 - [34mdebug[39m: Chrome strategy is dedicated-process2019-04-07 - [34mdebug[39m: Chrome custom launch options are executablePath=/tmp/jsreport/compile/jsreport-2.4.0-Bk_dhUp8V/chrome/chrome2019-04-07 - [34mdebug[39m: Extension fs-store was disabled2019-04-07 -

Comment: [34mdebug[39m: studio request logs are enabled (flush interval: 2000)2019-04-07 - [34mdebug[39m: Creating samples is disabled2019-04-07 - [34mdebug[39m: Extension public-templates was disabled2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Initializing jsreport@2.4.0 in development mode using configuration file: none2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension cli2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension handlebars2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension puppeteer-compile2019-04-07 -

Comment: [32minfo[39m: Using extension authentication2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension import-export2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension templates2019-04-07 -
 [32minfo[39m: Using extension freeze2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension debug2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension express2019-04-07T13:56:34.603Z - [32minfo[39m: Using extension tags2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension jsrender2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension data2019-04-07 -

Comment: [32minfo[39m: Using extension authorization2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension chrome-pdf2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension child-templates2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension licensing2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension pdf-utils2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension fs-store2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension browser-client2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension reports2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension text2019-04-07 -

Comment: [32minfo[39m: Using extension base2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension studio2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension version-control2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension scheduling2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension scripts2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension html-to-xlsx2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: html-to-xlsx detected chrome as available html engine2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension assets2019-04-07 -

Comment: [32minfo[39m: Using extension xlsx2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension sample-template2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension resources2019-04-07 - [32minfo[39m: Using extension public-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headless chrome requires some additional shared libraries that are not present in the default azure web app linux environment. However, you can use docker based azure web app and install these required libs.

```
RUN apt-get update && \   
    apt-get install -y gnupg  libgconf-2-4 wget && \
    wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable --no-install-recommends

ENV chrome:launchOptions:args --no-sandbox
```

See this in the documentation
https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-local#docker
https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-local#azure-web-apps

and example
https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-dotnet-example-docker

Comment: moving to docker based web app is not immediate choice as we already move to production. Fine to move to other Recipe can also be thought of that is available in Web App environment by default.